# Why does Sienna Brooks inject Robert Langdon with a sedative?

Tags: plot-explanation, inferno

Why does Sienna Brooks inject Robert Langdon with a sedative in *Inferno*, when she knows that she is supposed to drag him out of the make-do hospital to her make-do home? We see later that Langdon's reflexes alter because of the sedative and he's unable to move quickly which is required of him in this case.

Comment: It definitely *Inferno* and although I expect the Movie will be different from the book I'd guess this is answer on the Wikiepedia page... *"They gave Robert benzodiazepine drugs to erase his short-term memory"*

Comment: @Paulie_D That was earlier, though. He already had lost his memory when she supposedly injected him the sedative.